# Syntax error on if else statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm just writing a basic code that takes 2 inputs and an operator and solves. I have to code the program to tell it to not let a division of 0 happen but I my else keeps having an error message saying that there is a syntax error token. I'm not sure why because I have done if else statements in the past and it doesn't look any different. I am new at programming. 
Help would be appreciated

```
 if((operator == '/') && (operand2 == 0))
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Division by 0 not allowed"); 
   System.exit(0);
 else 
  add = operand1 + operand2;
  mult = operand1 * operand2; 
  sub = operand1 - operand2;
  div = operand1 / operand2;
  remainder = operand1 % operand2;
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: Where is your operator variable?? And you should put your if/else in a block for multiple statements.

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, you should add the `homework` tag.

Answer (score 5):

If you have more than one statement within a block, you need to surround it with braces:

```
if (...) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. I was messing around with those braces before I guess I missed it in the one place that was correct haha

Answer (score 1):

You need to have curly braces { } around the if and the else if there are more than one line of code under them. This is the reason you are having the issue

Answer (score 0):

As the others before me have stated, yes, you need to have curly braces surrounding your if statement bodys when they are more than one line. Java pretty much only sees this part of your code.

```
if((operator == '/') && (operand2 == 0))
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Division by 0 not allowed"); 
else 
  add = operand1 + operand2;
```

Now, however, if you were to add curly braces {} to your if and else blocks, Java would be able to read the whole code. It looks something like this

```
if((operator == '/') && (operand2 == 0))
{
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Division by 0 not allowed"); 
 System.exit(0);
}
else
{ 
 add = operand1 + operand2;
 mult = operand1 * operand2; 
 sub = operand1 - operand2;
 div = operand1 / operand2;
 remainder = operand1 % operand2;
}
```

Comment: Your first paragraph and code sample are wrong. What the compiler actually sees is `if((operator == '/') && (operand2 == 0))
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Division by 0 not allowed"); System.exit(0); else`, and without the `{}` the syntax error is because of the `else` with no matching `if` to start the block. (The `System.exit(0);` is still seen, however.) IOW, the `if` block is closed with the end of the call to `showMessageDialog()` and it's terminating `;`, leaving the call to `exit()` as a new single statement, followed by an orphaned `else`.